# DraggableFlatList onRef getting a wrong type with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-draggable-flatlist

I am using react-native-draggable-flatlist in ReactNative. I am interested in the ref to FlatList so that I can perform a scrollToIndex on it. Using the following code:

```
import React, {
    useEffect, createRef, useRef,
} from 'react'
import { ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import DraggableFlatList, {
    RenderItemParams, DragEndParams,
} from "react-native-draggable-flatlist"

export default function TasksList(props: Props) {

    const ref = createRef<DraggableFlatList<ITask>>()
    const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList<ITask> | null>(null)

    return (
        <DraggableFlatList
            ref={ref}
            onRef={flatListRef}
...
    )
}
```

I get the following Typescript error:

> Type 'MutableRefObject<(ComponentClass<FlatListProps &
> NativeViewGestureHandlerProps & RefAttributes, any> & { ...; }) |
> (FunctionComponent<...> & { ...; }) | null>' is not assignable to type
> '(ref: RefObject<FlatList>) => void'.   Type
> 'MutableRefObject<(ComponentClass<FlatListProps &
> NativeViewGestureHandlerProps & RefAttributes, any> & { ...; }) |
> (FunctionComponent<...> & { ...; }) | null>' provides no match for the
> signature '(ref: RefObject<FlatList>): void'.
> The expected type comes from property 'onRef' which is declared here
> on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> IntrinsicClassAttributes<DraggableFlatList> &
> Pick<Readonly<Modify<FlatListProps, { ...; } & Partial<...>>> &
> Readonly<...>, "ItemSeparatorComponent" | ... 150 more ... |
> "children"> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>'

How to fix the error so that I can use the ref/ onRef?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive you're not getting what `onRef` prop is expecting to get here. If you look closely at the error it says along the lines something like that:

```
'MutableRefObject<FlatList<ITask> | null>' is not 
    assignable to type '(ref: RefObject<FlatList<ITask>>) => void'.
```

So, it clearly expects a function and not a `RefObject`. You may also refer to the [source code](https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist/blob/eb040bb/src/index.tsx#L107) to verify that:

```ts
    ...
    onRef?: (ref: React.RefObject<FlatList<T>>) => void;
    ...
```

It expects a function that will be given a ref of `RefObject<FlatList<T>>` type.

You may fix your code rewriting it as:

```ts
    ....
    const ref = createRef<DraggableFlatList<ITask>>()
    const flatListRef = useRef<React.RefObject<FlatList<ITask>> | null>(null)

    return (
        <DraggableFlatList
            ref={ref}
            onRef={(ref) => { flatListRef.current = ref }}
```

So inside `flatListRef` ref via it's `current` property you'll have access to the underlying `FlatList` `ref`.

Comment: Thanks Aleks! No doubt I didn't know what I was doing ;-) With your help, I do now.